# QueryStringParameters not working on ASP.Net objectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, webforms, objectdatasource, querystringparameter

I can't seem to get the QueryStringParameters to work with an ObjectDataSource in ASP.Net webforms. Seems like I've done this a million times, but can't figure out why the following won't work at all (the parameters are completely ignored, though the querystring is being read if I test in the PageLoad event).

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods1" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCountMethod="GetProductsCount" SelectMethod="GetProductsByPageSort" TypeName="ExpressSelect.ProductData" DataObjectTypeName="ExpressSelect.SearchProduct">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="startRowIndex" QueryStringField="sri" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="10" Name="maximumRows" QueryStringField="rows" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The value of startRowIndex passed to the method is always 0 and the maximumRows is always -1 (even though the default should be 10).

To make sure the querystring was being read correctly, I ran the following to ensure the values are, indeed, there.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sri As String = Request.QueryString("sri")
    Dim rows As String = Request.QueryString("rows")
End Sub
```

And they are correct - the url looking like so:

```
http://localhost:49322/default?sri=5&rows=10
```

The method header:

```
    <DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, True)>
    Public Shared Function GetProductsByPageSort(ByVal startRowIndex As Integer, ByVal maximumRows As Integer) As DataTable
```

I've moved to MVC (been a while since I've had to edit some old webforms), so I think I just forgot something else to get the SelectParameters to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Paging was enabled. 
ODS QueryString Select parameters are ignored when paging is turned on. 
Apparently, the control has it's own querystring parameters internally (why the GridView & ListView is horrible for SEO out of the box - you have to do this from code-behind).